# In JavaScript, get high numbers in a set of numbers, based on variance

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers, variance

I have JavaScript code that grabs the highest part of a series of numbers.

Let's say I have a series of 10 numbers, such as `1, 3, 4, 4, 7, 15, 16, 16, 30, 31`. Let's say I want to grab the highest 25% (rounding up), then I end up with `16, 30, 31`. But just by looking at the results, the `16` doesn't "belong". Ideally I'd like to get a result of `30, 31` instead. (Note that this is just an example; in reality, I have sets of hundreds of numbers, and their numbers are pretty random.)

Is there a better way to grab the highest portion of a series of numbers, based on variance? And then all I'd have to do is specify the value of the variance until I get the numbers I want from multiple sets of numbers.

Comment: How do you know `16` doesn't "belong"? would `17` "belong"? How high would you need to go before it's acceptable?

Comment: I figure I could adjust the variance allowed in the top set with a variable, once the algorithm is written. Shouldn't that be the case? And in this example, I just wanted a small set to easily eyeball it, which is what I would do for several sample sets, before I unleashed the algorithm on every set I have. And I'm not really the best at terms used in statistics, otherwise I'd use the correct terms for sure. I guess I'm looking for X standard deviation-worth of values? But the top part of the set, not the mean.

Comment: You need to be more clear in what you're looking for.  What do you mean by "highest 25%"?  What to you mean by "based on variance"?  Variance is a measure of the deviation of numbers from the mean.  The population variance of your example is 16.05...how does that inform what numbers you include in the set?

Comment: Also, when you say "highest 25% (rounding up)", why wouldn't 16 be in that list?  25% of 10 is 2.5, rounding up, that's 3 numbers...if you're picking the highest 3, that's 16, 30, and 31.  Are you saying "at _most_, the top 25%, based on some additional criteria"?

Comment: Well I did include `16` in my example, when I grabbed the top 25%. I just wanted to show that sometimes the top 25% doesn't work and get me the results I want. The difference between 16 and 30 is too great, in this case; from my example, the `15, 16, 16` are clustered together, and then the `30, 31` are also together. So in the example, I'd want to return `30, 31` because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sequence = [14, 28, 20, 11, 7, 15, 18]; //all the numbers
var generalCap = Math.round(sequence.length / 4); //25%
var currenthighs = [];
function calculatehighs(strictness) {
    for(var i=0;i<sequence.length;i++) {
        var current = sequence[i];
        if(currentHighs.length > generalCap - 1) {
            var match = false;
            for(var n=0;n<currenthighs.length && !match;n++) {
                if(current > currenthighs[n]) {
                    currenthighs.splice(n); //delete one
                    currenthighs.push(current);
                    match = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            currenthighs.push(current); //if under 25% simply put it in the array
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<currenthighs.length;i++) {
        var difference = 0;
        for(n=0;n<currenthighs.length;n++) {
            difference += Math.abs(currenthighs[i] - currenthighs[n]);
        }
        if(difference > currenthighs[i] / strictness) {
            currenthighs.splice(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here this might work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want around top 25% of the set, and also the variance should be low. Define a function of variance of the subset and its size. (eg. *variance+abs(sizeOfSubset-idealSize) ).
Now start from smallest acceptable subset and iterate upto largest acceptable subset. Then pick subset that minimizes your function. The key here is to pick the function correctly, it will have a significant effect on your results. Also, you might want to normalize the variance as variances of larger numbers will be larger than that of smaller numbers. So, a sample objective function (i.e. the function to be minimized) could be

*variance/mean + abs(sizeOfSubset-idealSize)/totalSize.*